# LaravelMix、LaravelVIteでMaterializeCSSのAutoInitがエラーになる

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, webpack

### 概要

Laravelでmaterializecss（ https://materializeweb.com/ ）を使いたいのですが、
エラーになります。
この解決方法がわかりません。

### エラー内容

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "AutoInit", _materializecss_materialize_dist_js_materialize_min_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default() is undefined
```

### 書いたコード

単純に以下のものになります。
LaravelMixのコンパイルは通りますが、
ブラウザでアクセスした際にエラーになります。
**app.js**

```js
import './bootstrap';
import 'sweetalert2';
import M from '@materializecss/materialize/dist/js/materialize.min.js';

M.AutoInit();
```

**webpack/mix/js**

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css', [])
;
```

### 考察

`M.AutoInit();`でエラーになっていると思います。
これはmaterializecssのJavaScript関係を実行する際に実行しておかないと動かないようです。
公式には書かれています。
https://materializeweb.com/auto-init.html

なお、viteで同じようにしてみたのですが`M.AutoInit();`でエラーになって動かなかったため、
LaravelMixに変更してみましたが結局`M.AutoInit();`でエラーになり、こちらにて質問させていただいております。

### 環境

- windows11
- docker (WSL2 ubuntu)

  - PHP8.3
  - node 20
- Laravel v10.34.2
- materializecss 2.0.3-beta

---

こちら、原因をおわかりになる方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示をお願い致します。
よろしくお願いいたします。